# How to set a bean property before uploading a file using rich:fileUpload?

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, richfaces

My application has a modal panel where the user can upload files and choose a "document type" in a drop-down select.

I was using an `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` to set the document type value during the upload event, but sometimes the property is set **after** the upload has been processed. Probably it's happening because another request is being generated, and this request is handled by another web container thread.

```
<rich:modalPanel id="attachFiles" autosized="true">
    <h:form id="formUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h:selectOneMenu id="docType"  value="#{myMB.docType}" required="true" >
            <f:selectItems value="#{myMB.docTypesSelectItems}"  />
    </h:selectOneMenu>`
        <rich:fileUpload id="upload" fileUploadListener="#{myMB.handleUpload}">
            <a4j:support event="onupload">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{myMB.docType}" 
                    target="#{myMB.docType}" />
            </a4j:support>
        </rich:fileUpload>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

When it happens, the value of `myMB.docType`is null during the execution of `myMB.handleUpload`, which is not expected, since the field is supposed to be required.

Is there a way to assure that the method `myMB.handleUpload` is executed only **after** the property of `docType` has been set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{myMB.docType}" target="#{myMB.docType}" />
```

I don't get you. The target is the same as the value. You're basically setting the target's value with self. Isn't the value itself simply already `null`?

Anyway, I don't do RichFaces, so I can't go in detail, but I know that it's using Flash under the covers for the upload component and that such a construction usually fires a separate (and standalone) request which doesn't take all other HTML form parameters into account. The "normal" JSF inputs comes thereafter in a separate HTTP request. So you're kind of lost here without bringing in some nasty JS/ajax hacks. At least, in theory.

Your best bet is to get hold of the uploaded file as a bean propery in the listener method and then process that further in the normal bean's action method (the one attached to some `UICommand` component in the same form).

Comment: BalusC, I set the target to the same as the value because I didn't see other way to set the selected value of `<h:selectOneMenu` in `#{myMB.docType}`. Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is that the docType is linked to the file being uploaded. If it's processed only in the OK button, the value of docType will be the last one and not the value selected before uploading the file. For instance: the user can select docType1, upload a file, then change the combo value to docType2. Which docType he expects (from the user point of view) will be saved? I'm thinking about enabling the `rich:fileUpload` component only after the user chooses a value in docType `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

Comment: Another thing, is it supposed to represent the **content** type of the uploaded file? If so, why not just grab it from the headers and/or determine by file extension?

Comment: No, it is an internal classifier used by the end user. Something like: "report", "sales analysis", "internal email".

Comment: OK, makes sense. As to the selection problem, did you remove the unnecessary `f:setPropertyActionListener`?

Comment: BalusC, I removed the unnecessary `f:setPropertyActionListener` and adopted the strategy you suggested, handling the docType only when the user confirms the operation (triggered by a `UICommand`). The disadvantage is that now the user can only upload one file each time, but that's acceptable. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

Change

```
<a4j:support event="onupload">
```

to

```
<a4j:support event="onclick">
```

The set document type action will be executed before upload file. Exactly when the explorer file system is opened

Answer (score 0):

I would add Ajax capability to the select component instead. This way, the bean value is immediately updated each time the user changes the value of the select. Inside your file uploading method you can then rely on the bean value to represent the most recent selection the user has made.

You would only have to take care of the case, where the user starts the file upload without touching the select. Either you would need to have a sensible default value or you would have to take care of a non-selection and make the select field somehow required before uploading a file.