# Richfaces fileupload component - before file upload event

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, richfaces

I am using Richfaces fileupload component to upload some files. After I select a file, I would like to do something with the data, filename, etc before actually uploading the file. However, I cant seem to find the the before upload event handler event handler.

Question 1: What event is used to handle file selection -can I hook my code in there

Question 2: Is there an onbeforeUpload event?

Comment: What version of richfaces are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `filesubmit` event in your ajax listener:

```
<rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.listener}" id="upload" acceptedTypes="jpg, gif, png, bmp"
            ontyperejected="alert('Only JPG, GIF, PNG and BMP files are accepted');" maxFilesQuantity="5">
            <a4j:ajax event="filesubmit" execute="@none" render="info" />
</rich:fileUpload>
```

The `filesubmit` event is fired *before* the file is upload

Reference:

- [Richfaces HTML documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-Rich_inputs-richfileUpload)

Answer (score 0):

you can do any thing in the listner.

```
 public void listener(UploadEvent event) throws Exception{
    UploadItem item = event.getUploadItem();
    File file = new File();
    file.setLength(item.getData().length);
    file.setName(item.getFileName());
    file.setData(item.getData());
    files.add(file);

}
```

use [Primeface uploder](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf) . i think primeface is the best JSF framework.

Comment: Unfortunately, am stuck with Richfaces for now. While I would have prefered to use Primefaces, the project was initially implemented based on RF, I dont wanna start from scratch. In addition, by the time I call

Comment: In addition, by the time I call the listener, I dont have a chance anymore to manipulate the data. For example, say I wanted to show the filepath on the server where the file will reside after upload. At the moment when I select, i only get the file name of the file selected shown on the GUI, What i would ideally like to do is select a file and show the user the destination path on the server

Comment: i think you can get some help from this articla [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158505/how-to-set-a-bean-property-before-uploading-a-file-using-richfileupload)

Comment: and this too [link](http://ramannanda.blogspot.com/2010/10/richfaces-file-upload-tutorial.html)

Comment: in there i got this.

'  UploadItem item = event.getUploadItem();
 ****
    ***
  if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
  {
  FileVO fileVO = new FileVO();
   fileVO.setLength(item.getData().length); 
else{
   FacesMessage fmsg=new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Db error","Some Db error  has occured could not upload your files");
   fctx.addMessage(null, fmsg);
  }
 
  files.add(fileVO);
  uploadsAvailable--;
}'

Answer (score 0):

1) the component fires a "fileselect" event when you select a file.

2) not as such, but the component has "onbegin" attribute, you might be able to use that.